# Updating user location without generating new unique ID in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is what the Realtime Database in my Firebase looks like when sending the user's current location to it, without using a unique id.

However, when using push() in the code, it keeps on generating new ids every refresh of the location.

Is it possible to constantly update the user's location without generating a new unique id or remove the updating of the location completely?

Here is my activity for sending the location to the database.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLocation;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;
private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LatLng latLng;
private boolean isPermission;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if(requestSinglePermission()){

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        checkLocation();




    }



}

private boolean checkLocation() {

    if(!isLocationEnabled()){
        showAlert();
    }
    return isLocationEnabled();

}

private void showAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
            .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app")
            .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

private boolean requestSinglePermission() {

    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    isPermission = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    // check for permanent denial of permission
                    if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        isPermission = false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                }


            }).check();

    return isPermission;
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if(latLng!=null){

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker in Current Location"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,14F));

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    startLocationUpdates();
    mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLocation == null) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, this);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    LocationSend send = new LocationSend(
            location.getLongitude(),
            location.getLatitude()
    );
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.getKey();
    reference.child("User Location").setValue(send).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });




    latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(mGoogleApiClient !=null){
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();


    if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate solution would be to implement [Firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and use store the latitude and longitude like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
             |
             --- location
                   |
                   --- latitude: 37.421795
                   |
                   --- longitude: -122.13792
```

In this way, you'll always update the same location. Here is the required reference:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference locationRef = db.child("users").child(uid).child("location");
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go ahead and try this out.

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: I'm having trouble retrieving the location data and am getting Null Pointer Exceptions when following this path when referencing the database: 

db.child("users").child(uid).child("location");

Comment: Without seeing the entire code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hello, I've already posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568171/unable-to-retrieve-user-location-data-from-firebase-with-unique-key

Comment: @RafaelCampos I have just answered it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to generate new ids then firebase will replace your old values of latitude & longitude every time with the new values if they are different from existing values.

When push() function is get called then new id is generated. If you don't want to generate new id then you can use timestamp to identify when your latitude and longitude is updated using System.currentTimeMilliS() method.

Code will be like

```
LocationSend send = new LocationSend(
            location.getLongitude(),
            location.getLatitude(),
            System.currentTimeMillis()
    );
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this?