# Unable to retrieve user location data from Firebase with unique key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I've successfully added a unique key to my database schema in Firebase, instead of using `push()`, preventing it from generating new push keys whenever the location refreshes.

```html
{
  "Users" : {
    "RCX2HZXIwlSmMHFgDytf1DgZBgi2" : {
      "Alert Level" : "High",
      "Emergency Type" : "Natural Disaster",
      "User Location" : {
        "latitude" : 15.5352917,
        "longitude" : 120.7742867
      },
      "address" : "Lapaz Tarlac",
      "emergencyNum" : "0981232387346",
      "name" : "Rafael Campos",
      "phoneNum" : "0981233445675"
    }
  }
}
```

I checked my other app that retrieves the location from Realtime Databse and the user's location does not reflect at all on the map. I kept configuring the database references in code to get the correct path of the user's location but the app keeps crashing from NullPointerExceptions. How should I reference the correct child keys, especially the unique key of the users?

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityRetrieveMapsBinding binding;
private Location mLocation;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 1001;
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityRetrieveMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    checkLocation();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {

            final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates LS_state = locationSettingsResult.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(RetrieveMapsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkLocation() {

    if(!isLocationEnabled()){
        showAlert();
    }
    return isLocationEnabled();

}



private void showAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
            .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app")
            .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference locationRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("User Location");

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference locationRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("User Location");

    locationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Log.d("Tag", "latitude, longitude");
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(getCompleteAddress(latitude, longitude)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,14F));
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });


}



private String getCompleteAddress(double Latitude,double Longitude){

    String address = "";

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(RetrieveMapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

    try{

        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude,Longitude,1);

        if(address!=null){

            Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder stringBuilderReturnAddress =  new StringBuilder("");

            for(int i=0; i<=returnAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++){
                stringBuilderReturnAddress.append(returnAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }

            address = stringBuilderReturnAddress.toString();

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Address not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return address;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                // All required changes were successfully made

                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                // The user was asked to change settings but chose not to

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit: I've already added the changed code, as prescribed by Alex:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    DatabaseReference rootRef = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference locationRef = 
    rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("User Location");

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference locationRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("User Location");

    locationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Log.d("Tag", "latitude, longitude");
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(getCompleteAddress(latitude, longitude)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location,14F));
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        }
    });


}
```

I'm still not seeing the user's current location being reflected and having the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
at com.example.rescuealertadmin.RetrieveMapsActivity$4.onComplete(RetrieveMapsActivity.java:194)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the following reference:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("User Location");
```

Please note, that there is no need to looping through the results. You should only call `.child()` again on the `DataSnapshot` object as in the following lines of code:

```
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            double latitude = snapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitude = snapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "latitude, longitude");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
15.44318, 120.7148767
```

Comment: Just making sure, this is all inside the OnMapReady() right?

Comment: Yes, in the same place you already have it. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I'm still having errors with this code with NullPointerException

Comment: "I'm still having errors" doesn't provide enough information so I can further help. Please edit your question and add the changed code, so I can get a look at it. I personally tested this code and it worked.

Comment: I've already added the changed code. It's still not reflecting the user's current location on the map.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the changed code, to see it more clear.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the JSON file now.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error (NullPointerException)?

Comment: On this line of code:
double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

Comment: If you log the value of `uid`, is it the same as in the picture?

Comment: You mean get the value of the UID and put it in .child()? I haven't tried it yet but what I'm planning to do is to get multiple user locations, that's why I used the UIDs instead of just push().

Comment: Give a try with the hardcoded value of the UID and tell me if it works.

Comment: The user's location is still not reflecting after using the UID's value

Comment: Is your onComplete  even triggered?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to tell, but it's dislaying when the UID is not involved.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's dislaying when the UID is not involved"? The log statement ar printing the desired results?